# Google Forms Add-On - menu item not appearing on initial load after installing plugin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google-Forms add-on published. It has been approved by their API process and is published in the store.

When the add-on is first used, the add-on appears when you click the little puzzle piece ->

[image: google add-on icon]

, but, once it's clicked on, only the "help" menu item appears, it's missing the main "action" that the plugin exposes.  If *a new google form* is created, *then* the plugin shows all the options.

I'm sorry if this isn't clear, happy to add more details.   In my case, the "Upload" link is missing until a new form is created (which is really awful usability).

The relevant parts of the Google Apps script code looks like this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem("Upload", "processUpload")
    .addToUi();
}

function processUpload() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
```

Any ideas how to make that "Upload" link appear the first time the plugin is installed without requiring a new form be created?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259618/menu-items-do-not-appear-in-google-sheets-add-on , though that doesn't have a particularly good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the answer was also to add the `onInstall` hook (which just calls the onOpen already defined)

```
function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
};
```